# How can I apply a CSS class to HtmlTableCell?

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm working with WebForms.  `HtmlTableCell` does not have a `CssClass` property.  I can do this:

```
<td class="whatever"></td>
```

But not this:

```
myTableCell.Class = "whatever";
```

How can I apply a CSS class to my `HtmlTableCell`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Got it.

```
myTableCell.Attributes.Add("class", "whatever");
```

Comment: There it was all along, staring me in the face.  One minor change I'd make since `Attributes` is (essentially) a `Dictionary<string,string>`, I prefer the form: `myTableCell.Attributes["class"] = "whatever";`.

Answer (score 2):

Attributes property works too for CSS style.

For example:

```
myTableCell.Attributes.Add("style", "height: 30px; border: 1px solid;")
```